# CRON не выполняет задачу в указанное время

Tags: debian, cron

Настраиваю крон. Задание:

```
*/1 * * * * date >> /tmp/date
```

отрабатаывает без проблем.

Но если задать какое-то определённое время, например

```
12 11 * * * date >> /tmp/date
```

то новая строка не пропишется, а в логе крона будет такая запись:

> Dec 24 11:11:01 comp crontab[14558]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
>   Dec 24  11:11:33 comp crontab[14558]: (root) REPLACE (root)
>   Dec 24 11:11:33 comp crontab[14558]: (root) END EDIT (root)
>   **Dec 24 11:12:01 comp cron[584]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)**

прошу помочь разобраться

ОС: Debain 8

Comment: Не задавайте задание на следующую от текущего времени минуту. В следующую минуту cron только перечитывает конфиг. А выполнять он его начинает в послеследующую

Comment: @cronfy, тут, вероятно, зависит от реализации/сборки/настроек программы `/usr/sbin/cron`. на моей рабочей машине с реализацией от isc (сборка для debian/wheezy) такого не наблюдается — задача выполняется сразу. а автору вопроса стоит попробовать указывать время, отстоящее от текущего **больше** чем на одну минуту.

Answer (score 1):

возможно, процесс *cron* «считает», что работает в другом часовом поясе, нежели процесс *syslog* (именно он подставляет информацию о времени в файл, выдержка из которого приведена в вопросе).

такая несогласованность могла быть результатом, например, смены общесистемного часового пояса, но без перезапуска процесса *cron*.

значит, надо перезапустить *cron*:

```
$ sudo service cron restart
```

и попробовать ещё раз.

Answer (score 0):

перезапуск крона и вынос в /etc/crontab помогло,
в юзерские кроны сейчас добавить не могу - пик тайм, видимо и правда в часовом поясе дело - менялся на днях