# Почему cron не выполняет задание в указанное время?

Tags: debian, cron, crontab

Есть запись в cron:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/user/script.py
```

Задача стабильно выполняется каждую минуту.
Если указать определённое время:

```
0 20 * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/user/script.py
```

то cron не отрабатывает.
Debian 9
Читал подобный вопрос [CRON не выполняет задачу в указанное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607291/cron-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f), но советы не помогли.

Comment: Судя по всему пропущен один параметр

Comment: во-первых, в первом варианте уже ошибка: `*/1` писать не надо. надо писать просто `*`. во-вторых, по приведённой ссылке совета как такового нет. есть лишь напиминание о том, что существует такая штука как часовые пояса. и в разных часовых поясах время отличается. подождите сутки для полной увереннности, что задание **точно** не выполнилось.

Comment: Бывает, что ждут, что оно отработает в 00:20, а оно прописано на 20:00.

Answer (score 0):

А если написать правило так

```
0 20 0 * * ?
```